# server-to-server node.js ws websocket

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have two node.js apps on my sever and I wan't to send sever-server messages between them. I am testing by running the first app first and then starting the second.

App 1: I see console message `opened 1` but I don't see `Hi from 2`

```
var WebSocket = require('../node_modules/ws');
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8008');
ws.on('open', function() {
    console.log('opened 1');
    ws.on('message', function(_){
        console.log(_); 
    });
ws.send('Hi from 1');
});
```

App 2: I see console message `opened 2` but I don't see `Hi from 1`

```
var WebSocketServer = require('../node_modules/ws').Server
  , wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8008});
wss.on('connection', function(ws) {
    console.log('opened 2');
    ws.on('message', function(_) {
        console.log('received:',_);
    });
    ws.send('Hi from 2');
});
```

Why wont they talk to/hear each other?

Comment: If you're going from server to server, there is absolutely no need for web sockets.  I recommend a normal TCP connection instead.  From there, you can use one of the many RPC implementations that works over arbitrary streams.  https://www.npmjs.org/package/rpc-stream

Comment: tcp, net,  npm: json-socket responds for a while then stays open yet does not receive messages (with no error). Are they only meant for temporary use? that's even when pinging!

Comment: No, you can have TCP connections that runs for weeks.  Use a packet sniffer like Wireshark to see what's happening over the wire.  Determine if the problem is network connectivity, or a code issue. Also, be sure to re-connect in the event you get disconnected.

Comment: I don't get disconnected, the connection stays open but doesn't respond in any way to messages on both ends.

Comment: Well, post a new question with your code then.

Comment: ok, thanks will do tomorrow after I think a bit